# Missing connection notifications in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, notifications

My OS is Xubuntu 14.04 and if you are using it too, you've surely noticed that when internet connection is established, it gives a notification by default at the top right corner of monitor. It has a button `Don't show notification` and I pressed it accidentally. Now I missed the notifications so much and want it back! Does anybody know where is its setting to give it back?

I tried `notifications` panel in `settings`, but no change was observed.

Comment: [This old post](http://askubuntu.com/q/398436/37165) on Ask Ubuntu had asked similar question, from which I had adapted to restore notification when internet connection is established. Additionally, I have briefly covered for other network notification cases. Answered below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the notification setting can be restored via `gsettings`. The reason you didn't find the setting is because the it is *not* stored by Xubuntu notification daemon `xfce4-notifyd`.

### Reset network notification

The easiest way is to reset the network notification to default setting from command line. The following one-line command will restore notification when the Internet connection is established.

In the **Terminal**, type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications
```

The effect is immediate, so restart is unnecessary.

To see the notification, click on the indicator icon for networking in the Xfce panel, then select/deselect `Enable Networking` option. The notification will show up again as usual.

### Extra: Other network notifications

In case you accidentally pressed the **Don't show this message again** button for other network notifications, you can list them by running the following command.

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.nm-applet
```

The output will show list of keys as below.

```
stamp
disable-disconnected-notifications
disable-vpn-notifications
disable-connected-notifications
suppress-wireless-networks-available
show-applet
disable-wifi-create
```

Look for relevant ones that have `notifications` keyword. Then run the reset command with the key you wish to reset.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet [KEY]
```

Alternatively, you can choose to enable notification manually by running the set command with `false` option. Since the key names are named as `disable-`, the `false` option is correct.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet [KEY] false
```

Both methods have been tested working in Xubuntu 14.04.